# What can I use to replace my alert method?

Tags: javascript, alert

In this code I wait until creating the request (201 http status). I use an alert method however I'd like not use it. What can I replace alert method here?

I'm looking for something like a "do nothing" method.

```
if (createRequest.status == 201)
{
      ...code.....
}

else
{
  alert('wait');
}
```

Comment: you can do empty else method i.e. `else { //i am empty }`

Comment: There are some UI libraries that provide different kinds of alternative message dialogs. Or if this is just for you (during development) there is `console.info`.

Comment: I think this might be in the context of an Ajax call and the `alert` is used to block further script execution. Please provide more information, it really isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: @user125697 no, that's not work ;)

Comment: @user125697 don't worry the method  Boostrap's alert has helped already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some more fancy suff such as [Boostrap's alert](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) or [Bootstrap's popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) that are specially designed to handle these cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "do-nothing" method... then simply **get rid of the else**:

```
if (createRequest.status == 201) {
      ...code.....
}
```

If you really want to keep it (I don't know why, maybe you might want an alternative case in the future):

```
if (createRequest.status == 201) {
      ...code.....
}
else {
      // doing nothing
}
```

It's better to check if something worked via. console log generally:

```
else {
console.log("It didn't work!");
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and you want an alternative to alert, you can use jQuery [UIDialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Remove the else-statement. **#badpractice**

Better would be to keep the option for error handling (e.g. do something if `readyState === 4 && status !== 201`) for dealing with unexpected results. You could at least log this to console with something like

```
console.warn("Hey, I got an unexpected response. Status: " + status);
```

(Or maybe in this case you would really like to know about it and actually keep `alert()` or any other visual cue.)